# Laravel Pagination with get() function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-pagination

This is the controller function. I need to set pagination for this.

```
public function student_list(){
        $students = Student::orderBy('first_name')->get();
        $stu_na = "Test Page";
        return view('student/student_list', compact('stu_na', 'students'));
}
```

After reading documentation I tried following ways.

**1st Way :**  `$students = Student::orderBy('first_name')->get()->paginate(5);`

> Error :Method paginate does not exist.

**2nd way** : `$students = Student::orderBy('first_name')->paginate(5)->get();`

> Error : Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

How should I use paginate with my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `->get()`. `->paginate()` will execute the query internally itself.

```
$students = Student::orderBy('first_name')->paginate(5);
```